# How to use popToRoute method of navigator?

Tags: react-native, navigation

I have an app in react native,which has several scenes defined.Now I want to use popToRoute() method in backandroid code so that when i click on back button it will move to the specific scene using popToRoute method instead of using pop method which will go through the navigation stack.

This is my code of index.android.js ,here i defined all the navigation routes.

```
 class Flights extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}
  render() {
    return (

      <Navigator
          initialRoute={{id: 'App'}}
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
          configureScene={(route) => {
            if (route.sceneConfig) {
              return route.sceneConfig;
            }
            return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
          }} />


    );
  }
  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    var routeId = route.id;
    console.log(routeId);
    if (routeId === 'App') {

       console.log('App');
      return (

        <App
          navigator={navigator} route={route} />

      );
    }
    if (routeId === 'LoginPage') {
 console.log('round');     
     return (
        <AutoCompleteUI
          navigator={navigator} route={route}  />

      );
     }
     if (routeId === 'LoginPage1') {
 console.log('round');     
     return (
        <AutoCompleteUI1
          navigator={navigator} route={route}  />

      );
     }
       if (routeId === 'MainPage') {
        console.log('main');
       return (
        <MainPage
          navigator={navigator} route={route} />

      );

      }
    if (routeId === 'LoginPage') {
 console.log('login');     
     return (
        <AutocompleteExample
          navigator={navigator} route={route}  />

      );

    }

    if (routeId === 'NoNavigatorPage') {
      return (
        <NoNavigatorPage
            navigator={navigator} />
      );
    }
    return this.noRoute(navigator);

  }
  noRoute(navigator) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}
            onPress={() => navigator.pop()}>
          <Text style={{color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>请在 index.js 的 renderScene 中配置这个页面的路由</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Flights', () => Flights);
```

Now the question is how do I use popToRoute method in backAndroid code in any other scene to pop to specific scene??

Answer (score 0):

To make use of the routes in other files, you will need to create a routes.js file which holds all routes in a more global position and you can import it into any other .js files when you need it.

A typical routes.js file will be like this (see the following, you can also manage transitions here):

```
let Routes = {
  OnBoardView: {
    name: 'OnBoardView',
    component: OnBoardView,
    index: 0
  },
  KeyfactView: {
    name: 'KeyfactView',
    component: KeyfactView,
    index: 4,
    sceneConfig: Navigator.SceneConfigs.PushFromRight
  }
}

export Routes;
```

And in other view files, you can do this:

```
import Routes from 'routes';

...
this.props.navigator.popToRoute(Routes.KeyfactView);
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Nothing much really, but you will firstly need to import all the view components in header to use them.